# The DOM tree is not updated after changes during development with NextJS14

Tags: javascript, next.js

Help me please. I have a file .../src/app/layout.jsx (home page of NextJS 14)

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const data = await getAllProducts();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={nunito.className}>
        <div className={styles[`wrapper`]}>
          <StoreProvider products={data}>
            <Header />
            {children}
          </StoreProvider>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Footer`s component path .../src/app/ui/footer/footer.jsx

After "npm run dev" if I chenge something (for example, I added one word or something else in JSX) in Footer component, also as Header component, this change immediately takes effect in browser.

But if I want to change something else, in order for the change to take effect I have to restart the project with "npm run dev" in other case second+ change will not happen - DOM does not updates.

In other components that are located in other pages (for example component .../src/app/ui/allProducts/AllProducts.jsx in page .../src/app/products/page.jsx), changes occur without problems.

I think that the issue is caching, but I can’t figure out how to disable it.

I would be very grateful for your help, since I am a newbie and have not been able to figure it out for several days now.

I looked for information here, but I still didn’t understand what I needed https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching

I used  export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' in numerous of components and pages, but it did not help.